# "Cannot find symbol variable" in Android SDK

Tags: android, variables, sdk, android-studio

During compiling my new Android application Android Studio exit whit this error:
"Cannot find symbol variable percscon".

My code is

```
if(ulterioretext.equals("")) {
            ....
        } else {

            String uno =  (String) "1";
            float numbersconto = Float.valueOf(ulterioretext);

            if(numbersconto <= 9){
                String percscont = (String) uno + ".0" + ulterioretext;
            } else {
                String percscont = (String) uno + "." + ulterioretext;
            }

            float percscontfloat = Float.valueOf(percscont); <- The error is here

            ....
        }
```

If i put the "String percscont = (String) uno + ".0" + ulterioretext;" outside the if everything works fine, but if It is inside the "if" The compiler did not find the percscont variable. Why?

Thanks

Comment: From the code you just show it is not so easy to see, but I think you are using percscont variable in the first branch of your if. Can you please post the whole if code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot find symbol variable '''percscon'''.

And you have used variable

```
 float percscontfloat = Float.valueOf(percscont);
```

It must be typo.
No doubt

so as you have declared variable which has scope inside if and else block.

```
 if(numbersconto <= 9){
                String percscont = (String) uno + ".0" + ulterioretext;
            } else {
                String percscont = (String) uno + "." + ulterioretext;
            }
```

Outside this variable is not accessible.

So declare it outside or start of method or block and make it accessible after if-else.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself.

I had to initialize the variable outside the if and now works fine!

Thanks

Comment: Nice to see you take my advice and ignore it ;)

Comment: I did not ignore your advice. I publish my question, then i notice that I made that error and write my solution. But I did not saw other replies.

Answer (score 0):

If you declaring `percscont` variable in `if` scope then you cannot access it from outside, if you want to access outside from `if`  then declare in an upper scope.